When I replaced a ceiling fan, I noticed the fan circuit had about 30 V on it when the light circuit was on and vice versa
I took the old fan down.  To make sure I wired the light to the same switch, I tested the voltage at the outlet box in the ceiling before I hung the new fan.  When I turned on the light switch, I measured about 30 VAC on the fan circuit. I then turned off the light switch and turned on the fan switch (at the wall plate).  I found the same thing.
The supply voltage comes in on 2 conductor romex.  The hot is jumpered to both the light and fan switch.  3 conductor romex runs from the wall plate to ceiling fan.  The black wire runs to the lights, the red to the fan.  All commons are tied together.  There is a 3rd 2 conductor romex running through the wall plate box, so I assume this circuit powers other devices nearby.
When both switches are off, I get 0 VAC.  When both are on, I get 120 VAC.  When one is on, I get about 30 VAC on the circuit that is off and 90 VAC across the two hots (red and black).  I tested for a short circuit between red and black but did not find anything.
Is this normal?

You're picking up what's called phantom voltage.  Wires can pick up voltage from nearby wires through mutual capacitance, even though they are not actually connected.  Voltmeters have very high impedance, and can detect that.  Since you tested for a short circuit and didn't find anything, you should be OK.
